# can't drag items to outside of a scrollable container

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am having trouble trying to drag an item from outside a container that has multiple lists. Here a stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2uj5gh

I added some overflow:visible styles but them the container just grows when I try to move it around.

I found that you need to clone to outside before scrolling but I have no idea how to do that in angular and with this library that I have to use.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using Angular Material.

You can add `cdkDropList` for the list component and `cdkDrag` for the children component.

So, your list will look like:

```
<ul fd-list cdkDropList>
  <ng-container>
    <li
      fd-list-item
      fd-dnd-item
      cdkDrag
      *ngFor="let value of values; trackBy: trackByFn"
    >
      <span fd-list-title> List item {{ value }} </span>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Read more about Drag and Drop in Angular Material [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

If you want to fully implement it, you can take a look at [this simple example](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-sorting).

Comment: So strange, I thought their directives just do that (fd-dnd-item), but I guess I was wrong, doing what you said actually worked. thanks